# How to get / view the log history of multiple git repositories in tfs

Tags: git, logging, github, tfs, history

Im using tfs and I need to view the log history of all the git repositories that are present. What is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **git log** for tracking multiple repositories, the git log output is very configurable so its really easy to get a clearer picture with the useful options included.

Install [git bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win) **>** Navigate to the local repository **>** Right click **.git** or **Project folder** **>** Git Bash Here > Run git log command

**Example:**

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

You can also run `gitk --all` to see the details.

For details please see: [Git Log Makes Multiple Repos Easier to Track](http://jr0cket.co.uk/2013/01/git-log-makes-multiple-repos-easier-to.html.html)

[image]

Comment: @Jai Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this ?

Comment: I came to this question looking for a combined history of multiple repositories.  This looks like it shows history of one repository at a time.

Comment: Yeah, this answer seems to be about multiple remotes.

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2022 and it seems we still can't see the history of multiple projects/repositories in one view. This is a basic and frequently used function that has existed since the days of TFS. But it seems to have been missed with the VS/Git integration. Hopefully someone comes up with a solution.